# Without g++ optimization, a complex template class function fails

Tags: c++, templates, matrix, g++, corruption

I am creating a floating point matrix template class. The class declaration is shown below only with relevant functions and members.

```
// columns, rows
template <unsigned int c, unsigned int r>
class Matrix {
 public:
  Matrix(float value);

  float& At(unsigned int x, unsigned int y);
  float const& At(unsigned int x, unsigned int y) const;
  template <unsigned int p> Matrix<p, r> MultipliedBy(Matrix<p, c> const& other);

 private:
  // column-major ordering
  float data_[c][r];
}
```

The implementations for each of the above functions follow.

```
template <unsigned int c, unsigned int r>
Matrix<c, r>::Matrix(float value) {
  std::fill(&data_[0][0], &data_[c][r], value);
}

template <unsigned int c, unsigned int r>
float& Matrix<c, r>::At(unsigned int x, unsigned int y) {
  if (x >= c || y >= r) {
    return data_[0][0];
  }

  return data_[x][y];
}

template <unsigned int c, unsigned int r>
float const& Matrix<c, r>::At(unsigned int x, unsigned int y) const {
  if (x >= c || y >= r) {
    return data_[0][0];
  }

  return data_[x][y];
}

template <unsigned int c, unsigned int r>
template <unsigned int p>
Matrix<p, r> Matrix<c, r>::MultipliedBy(Matrix<p, c> const& other) {
  Matrix<p, r> result(0.0f);

  for (unsigned int x = 0; x < c; x++) {
    for (unsigned int y = 0; y < r; y++) {
      for (unsigned int z = 0; z < p; z++) {
        result.At(z, y) += At(x, y) * other.At(z, x);
      }
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

Now, a few lines of test code.

```
Matrix<4, 4> m1;

// m1 set to
//
//  1   2   3   4
//  5   6   7   8
//  9   10  11  12
//  13  14  15  16

Matrix<1, 4> m2;

// m2 set to
//
//  6
//  3
//  8
//  9

Matrix<1, 4> m3 = m1.MultipliedBy(m2);
```

Here's where things get weird. When compiled (using `g++`) with no optimization (`-O0`):

```
// m3 contains
//  0
//  0
//  0
//  0
```

With any optimization (`-O1`, `-O2`, or `-O3`):

```
// m3 contains
//  210
//  236
//  262
//  288
```

Note that even with the optimization, the answer is incorrect (verified with an external calculator). So I narrowed it down to this call in `MultipliedBy`:

```
Matrix<p, r> result(0.0f);
```

If I instantiate `result` in any way `other` becomes invalidated (all `data_` values set to `0.0f`). Before the allocation/initialization of `result`, `other` is still valid (`6, 3, 8, 9`).

It is worth noting that if I multiply two matrices of the same (square) dimension, I get a completely valid and correct output, regardless of the optimization level.

Anyone have a clue what in the world `g++` is pulling here? I'm running `g++ (GCC) 4.6.1` on `mingw`... might this have something to do with the problem?

Comment: By the way, your identity matrix is wrong: it should be `diag(1)`, not `diag(0)`. What you call `Identity` is just `Zero`.

Comment: Shoot, thank you. Linear algebra and late night coding don't mix. I'm editing the post to reflect this.

Comment: What happens when you remove the "const" version of the "At" method. I have a hunch that the compiler is getting confused.  Did you try putting print statements on each method to see which version is getting called?

Comment: Consider renaming "At" to be "GetAt" and "SetAt" explicitly.

Comment: The const overload is being called properly. I am fairly certain this paradigm is common.

Comment: col x row Indexing is a bit confusing, normaly one defines a matrix as rows x cols

Comment: I am under the impression that column-major ordering (which is what OpenGL's `glLoadMatrix` uses) defines `columns x rows`. Am I mistaken? If I am, this would explain my erroneous calculations...

Comment: I didn't mean your definition of the 2d array, just meant the ordering of the template parameters. Don't know about OpenGL but in Linear Algebra its rowsxcols.

Comment: I had some weird combination of `columns x rows` and `rows x columns` calculations going on in my code. Standardizing everything to `rows x columns` as per your suggestion fixed my multiplication results. Thank you, P3trus!

Comment: No Problem :) By the way if you have to do a lot of matrix calculations I wouldn't reinvent the weel. You could use some of the mature matrix libraries. They are stable, have more features, and are almost always faster. E.g. [link](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) is pretty awesome. I'm using it for numerical calculations but it has OpenGl bindings as well(but I havent used them). Might save u some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&data_[c][r]` is perhaps wrong: it's `data_ + (c*r + r) * FS`, whereas you perhaps need `&data_[c-1][r-1] + FS`, which is `data_ + ((c-1)*r + (r-1) + 1) * FS`, which is `data_ + c*r * FS`.

(Here `FS == sizeof(float)`.)

Your last item is `data_[c-1][r-1]`, so one past last would be `data_[c-1][r]`, not `data_[c][r]`.

Comment: A classic example of overlooking simple matters... Thank you very much!